# Campaign tracking for a Flutter application (iOS & Android)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I have a mobile flutter app, we wanted to start advertising with influencers on Instagram, so we want to track install and sales for each one, can tracking be done by UTM google analytics?

I use firebase analytics on my app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.